# Could my Triclops exist?

Tags: science-based, biology, creature-design, evolution, mythical-creatures

Around 5 million years ago, a group of primates diverged from early Baboon ancestors migrated into Sicily becoming Triclopes (here's a rough mock up of what a Triclops skull might look like):
[image]

some basic characteristics of these Triclopes include:

- being 7.7 feet tall and weighing 333 lbs
- having an average have a life span of 70-80 years (barring major injuries)
- having a slightly larger eye in the center of their face with two smaller eyes below it
- having elephant like tusks
- are omnivorous but do lean more toward the carnivorous side
- having an improved sense of hearing and smell
- are bipedal
- are slightly hairier than a human
- having lost their tails
- exist in small packs which they are fiercely loyal to
- having 0.5 in (12.7 mm) thick skin
- having tool use slightly below that of homo erectus

Given these characteristics, could such a creature realistically exist, and what evolutionary pressures would lead to them? Magic does not exist in my story.

I know this question was originally about cyclopes but after some reconsideration I've decided to change it. I hope it doesn't affect things to much.

Comment: Possible duplicate https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/30163/30492

Comment: @L.Dutch-ReinstateMonica that one explains the one eye thing but not the tusks part

Comment: You might want to focus on just one problem at a time. You'll also need to clarify things like evolutionary time-frame. Otherwise, the only viable answer to the question set is: *well, yes of course this kind of Cyclops can exist --- it's your world after all!*

Comment: @elemtilas ok my Cyclopes diverged from early Baboon ancestors around 5 million years ago

Comment: I'm astonished by the edit. It has the effect of radically changing the question without invalidating existing answer - bravo for that.

Comment: Please not that the Greek for "three-eyed" is *τριόφθαλμος* (*triophthalmos*). \*\**Triclops* doesn't mean anything in Greek. (*Cyclops* means "round-eyed", not "one-eyed"; it comes from *κύκλος* (*kyklos*), "circle", and *ὠπή* (*ōpē*), "sight".) You may try to coin the new word *triops*, which *could* have been made in Greek, but wasn't.

Comment: Apparently, yes. I'm not sure about how the size of eyes, BUT it's not impossible. See the first image in this link: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diprosopus and you'll see that maybe the eye in the center might have appeared as a similar phenomenon that was somehow an advantage (also, see how the central eye is naturally larger than the other normal sized eyes)

Comment: @ProjectApex the center eye isn't significantly larger than the other just didn't know how to get that across

Comment: Please don't bump your post by making small changes to the post. This pushes other questions down on the front page, and we don't like that. Only make substantive edits; and please batch up your changes and limit yourself to at most a few edits per day. You might find https://stackedit.io/ useful for revising your post offline.

Comment: @L.Dutch-ReinstateMonica ok i just keep finding little things that i'm not satisfied with so understood

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yeah, in all honesty, cyclops as a whole are unlikely. You see, evolution favors traits that either allow you to survive better or allow you to reproduce better. And I doubt any kind of sexual selection would ever favor an eye over two. Not only you'd be reducing decently the creature's field of vision, they'd loose the ability to perceive depth, which is especially important for predators that rely on vision. It would also require for the single eye socket to be moved to the center of the face if you want symmetry and to maximize the field of vision on the front of the creature. It might be easier to simply remove both eyes altogether, or have something like 3 eyes.

Sorry, but basically it'd be easier for a creature to develop all of your other traits at once than for it to develop a single eye. I'd suggest having hippo tusks over an elephant's, unless it doesn't use its mouth to bite down on prey. Also your creature will need a decent enough ability with tool making to survive without nails, kinda like we did.

So, summing up, except for the single eye part, there's nothing too bad with your creature. It will likely inhabit more extreme climates to need such thick skin, most likely mildly colder regions to need that extra fur we lack and the tusks, in case they somehow don't interfere in hunting or feeding, are likely used during mating season and could develop as a sign of superiority among the species. But the eyes, just add one more, reptiles have rudimentary third eyes, so it's not impossible your animal once did too and it evolved into a more complex eye. it'll be much easier to evolve than it having a single eye and being viable as a hunter, unless they have something like a very, very specific case of polycoria and an incredibly large eye, and even that is way more unlikely to work out than simply sacrificing the eyes and relying on sound and smell to navigate.

Comment: The triclops has three eyes, not one

Comment: @Ichthys King compare the date and time of my answer with the last time this question was edited and you will understand :-).